# How do you add a class to parents only if two separate child divs are present

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How do you add a class to parents only if two separate child divs are present?

The code here works if the two classes are present in a child

```
$('.class1.class2').parents().addClass('newclass');

<div class="parentdiv">
<div class="class1 class2">        
</div>
```

I am trying to add class to parentdiv only if class1 and class2 are children

```
<div class="parentdiv">
<div class="class1">
</div>
<div class="someother">
</div>
<div class="class2">    
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `.filter` to select only those elements which satisfy condition provided in `callback`

```js
var filtered = $('.parentdiv').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('.class1').length > 0 && $(this).find('.class2').length > 0;
});
filtered.addClass('newclass')
```

```css
.newclass {
  border: 2px black dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentdiv">
  <div class="class1">
    Hello class1
  </div>
  <div class="someother">
  </div>
  <div class="class2">
    Hello class2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Used this solution as in the final code the child divs were several divs deep and need to use .find

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:has()` with selector `.class1 ~ .class2, .class2 ~ .class 1` to select `.parentdiv` element where `.class1` or `.class2` is child element is a general sibling of `.class2` or `.class1` respectively. If requirement is to select `.parentdiv` only if `.class1` is followed by `.class2` you can use selector `.class1 ~ .class2`

```js
$(".parentdiv:has(.class1 ~ .class2, .class2 ~ .class 1)")
.addClass("selected");
```

```css
.selected {
  color:olive;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentdiv">
<div class="class1">class1
</div>
<div class="someother">smoother
</div>
<div class="class2">class2
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentdiv">
<div class="class1">class1
</div>
<div class="someother">smoother
</div>
<div class="class3">class3
</div>
```